# Update Django database after drag & drop through javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I want to do a kanban table(project management) but I have no ideea how to save the modification in database after I drop a task(from todo to in progress for example).
This is how my model looks

```
class Task(models.Model):
    TODO = 1
    INPROGRESS = 2
    DONE = 3
    STATUS_TYPES = (
        (TODO, 'To do'),
        (INPROGRESS, 'In progress'),
        (DONE, 'Done'),
    )

    taskid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,default = increment_booking_number)
    projectcode = models.ForeignKey('Project', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='projectid')
    taskname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    taskdescription = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    task_status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices = STATUS_TYPES, blank=True, null=True)
```

here is my javascript for drag and drop:
https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/pAcECud8nRItO5nJefYF0w

Any help please?

[This is how the table should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8oxe.png)

Comment: On what modelfield do you save modifications when the task is dropped ? Have you thought  using ajax ?

Comment: In task_status @Lindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommand you to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) to achieve your goal, the reason is that you probably don't want to refresh your page on each drop.

Of course the code below is to give you an idea on how it should work, but you'll have to modify it a bit according to your own JavaScript.

```
#You might have a different drop trigger, configure to your need.
$(document).on('drop', '.your_dropped_task', function(e){ 
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/your_url/',
        data:{
            #You probably store your drop status on your dropped task.
            #You'll have to fetch it.
            task_status:$('this_dropped_task_new_val').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('#your_form input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
    });
});
```

This is rough, but this will definitely give you an idea of what you have to do.

Comment: Thank you very much! Tell me please what "#your_form" should be? Because I don't have any form for drag and drop. "/your_url/" should be the url of where i have the kanban table?

Comment: @alexito since you're using Django you probably have some `{% csrf_token %}` right ? This is just the security token so your form goes through. You need to have `<form id="your_form">...</form>` to be able to POST.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks

Comment: in my template I have
<form id="board_form">
{% csrf_token %}
...
 </form>

and in js
https://pastebin.com/Rk7ZYbCa

It does the post but not the modifications in database..

Comment: If the POST goes through, you'll have to point it on your view where you'll save the informations. AJAX won't save it for you, if this answer helped you please mark it as solved. I recommend you to use the pdb debugger`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html. Lastly, you also have to post the dropped_task since you need to know which task to save with the new status.